# Extracting href URL with Python Requests

Tags: python, python-3.x, xpath, python-requests, lxml

I would like to extract the URL from an xpath using the requests package in python. I can get the text but nothing I try gives the URL. Can anyone help?

```
ipdb> webpage.xpath(xpath_url + '/text()')
['Text of the URL']
ipdb> webpage.xpath(xpath_url + '/a()')
*** lxml.etree.XPathEvalError: Invalid expression
ipdb> webpage.xpath(xpath_url + '/href()')
*** lxml.etree.XPathEvalError: Invalid expression
ipdb> webpage.xpath(xpath_url + '/url()')
*** lxml.etree.XPathEvalError: Invalid expression
```

I used this tutorial to get started: http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/scenarios/scrape/

It seems like it should be easy, but nothing comes up during my searching.

Thank you.

Comment: Can you provide the value of xpath_url? On the first line it looks like the xpath is interpreted correctly but the following xpath statements may be incorrect.

Comment: @jeedo Your comment helped me realise that my xpath finished with "div/h2/a" and so adding just `/@href` as per jeremija's answer would suffice. Thank you.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Have you tried `webpage.xpath(xpath_url + '/@href')`?

Here is the full code:

```
from lxml import html
import requests

page = requests.get('http://econpy.pythonanywhere.com/ex/001.html')
webpage = html.fromstring(page.content)

webpage.xpath('//a/@href')
```

The result should be:

```
[
  'http://econpy.pythonanywhere.com/ex/002.html',
  'http://econpy.pythonanywhere.com/ex/003.html', 
  'http://econpy.pythonanywhere.com/ex/004.html',
  'http://econpy.pythonanywhere.com/ex/005.html'
]
```

Comment: Thank you! `@href` works. Now I need to go and learn why it's `text()` for text and `@href` for href.

Comment: I believe that's because `@` is used for referencing element's attributes, and `text()` returns the content of the selected node(s).

Comment: This was exactly what I needed - thanks!

Answer (score 5):

You would be better served using [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = requests.get('testurl.com')
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml") # lxml is just the parser for reading the html
soup.find_all('a') # this is the line that does what you want
```

You can print that line, add it to lists, etc.  To iterate through it, use:

```
links = soup.find_all('a')
for link in links:
    print(link.get('href'))
```

Comment: It seems bs4 is a popular way to do this. In this case, I wanted to stay with python requests, but this is certainly useful for future reference. Thank you.

Comment: placeholder - you would actually use:

`links = soup.find_all('a')

for link in links:
    print(link.get('href'))
`

I don't know why I wrote it that way some years ago - fixed now.

Answer (score 1):

with the benefits of a context manager:

```
with requests_html.HTMLSession() as s:
    try:
        r = s.get('http://econpy.pythonanywhere.com/ex/001.html')
        links = r.html.links
        for link in links:
            print(link)
    except:
        pass
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from requests_html import HTMLSession
session = HTMLSession()
r = session.get('https://www.***.com')
r.html.links
```

[Requests-HTML](https://html.python-requests.org)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it easily with selenium.

```
link = webpage.find_elemnt_by_xpath(*xpath url to element with link)
url = link.get_attribute('href')
```